# Uploading android library to jCenter bintray

Tags: android, maven, android-library, jcenter

Getting this issue *No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices* when I am building library

**Project build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

**Library build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

Comment: Why is down voted?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet. I haven't worked after that.

Comment: ouh ok, if you find a solution please post. btw, i upvote because it didn't seem fair that somebody downvoted the question BUT you could improve it a little bit, like adding some more explanation and contexts

Comment: Ya sure brother I will do that and thanks for the advice

Comment: btw i just managed to publish a library with jitpack.io it was kind of easy

Comment: ok thanks brother I will try that library, stuck with other project